# how to put more than one places with google maps in a single web page

Tags: jquery-ui, google-maps

I want to put more than one google map in a single web page
I am using google map api v3 for loading the google maps, I did the single map in a web page but I wanted to put more than one google maps of different locations

Here is the code:

```
<html> 
 <head> 
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
 <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Dynamic Loading</title> 
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
   function handleApiReady() { 
     var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(23.038587, 72.478253); 
     var myOptions = { 
       zoom: 8, 
       center: myLatlng, 
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
     } 
     var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas1"),
myOptions); 

     var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas2"),
myOptions); 
   } 
 </script> 
 </head> 
 <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;"> 
   <div id="map_canvas1" style="width:400px; height:400px"></div>
   <div id="map_canvas2" style="width:400px; height:400px"></div> 
   <script type="text/javascript"
src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=handleApiReady
"></script> 
 </body> 
 </html>
```

[google map 1](https://maps.google.co.in/maps?f=q&source=embed&hl=en&geocode=&q=Star%20Bazar,iscon%20mall%20ahmedabad&aq=&sll=23.047624,72.542513&sspn=0.085772,0.168056&gl=in&ie=UTF8&hq=Star%20Bazar,iscon%20mall&hnear=Ahmedabad,%20Gujarat&t=m&cid=8957318216217861802&ll=23.027766,72.519035&spn=0.014929,0.053387&z=14&iwloc=A)

[Google map 2](https://maps.google.co.in/maps?f=q&source=embed&hl=en&geocode=&q=Star%20Bazar,%20Koramangala,%20Bangalore,%20Karnataka&aq=0&oq=Star%20Bazar,%20ko&sll=19.883943,75.37282&sspn=0.043828,0.084028&gl=in&ie=UTF8&hq=Star%20Bazar,%20Koramangala,%20Bangalore,%20Karnataka&t=m&cid=1973246869586064139&hnear=&ll=12.936892,77.610683&spn=0.01581,0.053387&z=14&iwloc=A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is stopping you from giving a try. Here is a fiddle that demonstrates two maps with different locations-

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NhLss/)

JS-

```
var moptions1 = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.669, 77.709),
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var moptions2 = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.669, 77.709),
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map1"), moptions1);

map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map2"), moptions2);
```